# Was Xavier responsible for the Westchester Incident?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, logan

If you go to the [wiki page](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Logan_(film)) for *Logan*, it states in the plot section that

> They care for a senile Charles Xavier, who had inadvertently killed several of his X-Men in a seizure-induced psychic attack a year earlier.

But there's no citation for this, and from what I remember the movie left it intentionally ambiguous. However, it seems to be an accepted fact that the above is what happened. The movie itself is clearly based on the "[Old Man Logan](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Man_Logan_(Event))" series of comics, in which

> Logan kills all of the X-Men, believing them to be villains attacking the school, when in reality it is a hallucination caused by Mysterio.

Obviously there are things, such as characters, that Fox can't include in their X-Men Movieverse, so some details get changed, but to me it seems to be a significant change to have the guilty party be Xavier in place of Logan.

Is there anything that might provide some clarification one way or another as to whether Xavier was

> the killer of the X-Men, or merely the cause of Logan's hallucination?

The latter of course being more in keeping with the comic story?

Comment: it is stated on the news that a westchester accident in which 7 mutants were killed last year, and thats the incident in question with xavier.

Comment: There is nothing indicating that Logan killed the X-Men, and the similarities to *Old Man Logan* end at "logan is old, and goes on a road trip"

Comment: He has nightmares in which "hurts people". Granted, Wolverine kills lots of people, but I don't those kills cause him to have _Nightmares_ in the same way that hurting people close to him might. As for the news story, it might state that some mutants died, but does it say _how_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Undoubtedly, it was Charles Xavier

According to the recently released screenplay for *Logan*, Charles remembers that he was the one who caused the incident at Westchester. He confesses it to 'Logan' in his dying moments:

[image]

> ...This was, without a doubt, the most splendid night I’ve had in a
> long time. ...but then...
> As Logan takes another step toward Laura, Charles trembles. He does not look away from the window.
> CHARLES (CONT'D)
> ...I don’t deserve it, do I?
> (then)
> ...I did something... unspeakable.
> Logan turns.
> CHARLES (CONT'D)
> **I remembered what happened in Westchester. This was not the first time I've hurt people.**
> (pain fills his eyes)
> Until today, I didn’t know. You wouldn’t tell me. We just kept running from it. I’m done running.

Earlier in the movie, it is confirmed that the 'Westchester Incident' caused the deaths of 50 people (most likely Mutants).

[image]

> The sun breaks over the horizon. The radio chatters with breaking news reports on the event at the Casino-- speculation of a gas leak or food poisoning.
> REPORTER (ON RADIO)
> `...some noting a similarity to the incident last year in Westchester, New York that left 50 dead, and twice that many injured--`
> Logan SNAPS off the radio, quickly looks in back to see if Charles overheard it. Charles was sleeping. Opens his eyes.

You can hear the radio in the pickup truck that compares the hotel incident to the Westchester Incident, coupled with Logan's reaction to the story and his not wanting Charles to hear it tell us that it was indeed Charles.

Comment: Hard to argue with a screenplay. New accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

First off, the movie is *not* based in any meaningful way on *Old Man Logan*. At best, the writers thought the title sounded cool, but other than Logan being old and going on a road trip, every significant detail about the movie and comics are different.

In the movie, we never get *proof* that Xavier is the one responsible for the Westchester incident that

> killed 7 mutants, likely X-Men.

But the clues pointing to Xavier being responsible are scattered throughout the movie:

- Xavier repeatedly has seizures that send his power running amok.
- At least one of these happens in public, and the news directly connects the effects of it to the Westchester incident.
- Near the end of the movie,

  > Xavier appears to "remember" the incident, which he had presumably forgotten, and be extremely regretful about it.

If you put those pieces all together, it seems likely that Xavier was the one responsible for that incident. But it's also important to note that the Westchester incident is *not* the reason (or at least, not the only reason) there aren't any mutants anymore. That explanation is given elsewhere in the movie.